# transform: scale and positioning

Tags: css

How is that when I apply transform scale the "z-index is changed" ?
What i'm I missing ? Is there any "trick" for playing with transform ?

```
.thumb > a .img-cover{
    -webkit-transition: all 1.2s ease-out;border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
.img-cover{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.img-cover:before{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
    content:"";
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0 100px #f0f;}
.thumb > a:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
} ​
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <article class="thumb">
       <a href="#">
          <div class="img-cover"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/120"/></div>
          <span>thumb-desc</span>
       </a>
    </article>
</div>​
```

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8uhNK/9/)

Comment: You are missing the term "**stacking context**", which you can read about in Philip Walton's article, [What No One Told You About Z-Index](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/). (A new stacking context is created for the <html>, for the positioned elements having a z-index other than auto, for elements with opacity less than 1, for **transforms**, filters, css-regions, paged media etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the `z-index` yourself so it would do it for you.

```
.img-cover:before{
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
    content:"";
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0 100px #f0f;}
.thumb > a:hover img {
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

**[Example Code](http://jsfiddle.net/8uhNK/11/)**

Answer (score 0):

When property `position: absolute` is set, the object is out of the flow. This is why alignment is different and looks like z-index had changed. Manual setting z-index could solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Give **z-index** to your `.img-cover:before` on `a:hover`. Write like this:

```
.thumb > a:hover .img-cover:before{
    z-index:2;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/8uhNK/12/

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself, the "z-index is changed". So you have to set the `z-index` of `.img-cover` and `.img-cover:before`.The `z-index` of `.img-cover` has to have a lower value than the `z-index` of `.img-cover:before`.

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/8uhNK/10/